# UITableView - using reloadRowsAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I have a`UITableView` with delegate methods declared. The`numberOfRows` &`numberOfSections` are updated dynamically.

```
 (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{}

 (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:
```

Instead of using the `[tableView reloadData]`, I would need to use`reloadRowsAtIndexPath`.

However I get a crash with invalid number of rows. How do I handle the dataSource changes? Lets says I have an array of count 10, and when I reload the`UITableView` using`UIRefreshControls` by pulling, and the data from the server. From 10, if the count of array drops to 1, how will I handle`reloadRowsAtIndexPath`?

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[self.tableView indexPathForVisibleRows] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]
```

There seems to be a crash when this is called. How would I handle change in data array's count?

Comment: there might be multiple sections. the section can change on refreshing the data

Comment: Then you could use an indexset of the sections that are involved via `- reloadSections:withRowAnimation:` ...

Answer (score 1):

To reload specific cells of Tableview the method is **reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:** not **reloadRowsAtIndexPath**

```
    [self.tableview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[self.tableview indexPathsForVisibleRows] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

However for reloadRowsAtIndexPaths to work properly datasource needs to be consistant. As Indexpaths are already loaded.

If you still use this method, You will get either arrayIndexOutofBound error or duplicate values in cells(depending on increase or decrease in datasource).

Answer (score 1):

```
    //call begin and end updates while performing some hard core actions  on tableview
    [My_Table beginupdates];
    [My_Table reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[My_Table indexPathsForVisibleRows] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [My_Table endupdates];
    hope it will helps you.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this.

```
[tblMe beginUpdates];
[tblMe reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0], nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[tblMe endUpdates];
```

Hope this may help !!!